# Change images from a select field using Javascript

Tags: javascript, forms, debugging

So I'm trying to change an image based on which option the user selects from a dropdown menu. My images for now are "cyan.png", "magenta.png", "yellow.png", "black.png", and "fuschia.png".

My HTML

```
<select name="color" multiple>
<option>Cyan</option>
<option>Magenta</option>
<option>Yellow</option>
<option>Black</option>
<option>Fuschia</option>
</select>
```

My JavaScript

```
// This part tries to load all images onto the carArray variable
var nameArray = new Array("cyan.png", "magenta.png", "yellow.png", "black.png", "fuschia.png");
var carArray = new Array;

for(var i = 0; i < carArray.length; i++) {
    carArray[i] = new Image;
    carArray[i].src = nameArray[i];
}

// This part tries (and fails) to change the image when the user selects a color from a dropdown menu
window.onload = function() {
    var colorPicker = document.getElementsByName("color").selectedIndex;
    var options = document.getElementsByName("color").options;

    document.getElementById("photo").src = carArray[options[colorPicker];
}
```

Could you please help me understand what the problem is, and how to fix it.

Comment: What is the console telling you? Maybe that there is a closing square bracket missing at the end of the onload function? Or maybe the problem is that you're binding the function to the onload event while you should assign it to the onchange of the select tag?

Comment: okay, I was missing a square bracket in the carArray[options[colorPicker] part. And i changed the binding of the function to onchange. Thing is, I still can't change images

Comment: Inside the `window.onload` event bind the `onchange` event to `document.getElementById('color')`, it should do the trick

Comment: I get this error message now:

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read propert 'undefined' of undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you bind your function on `window.onload`, it will only fire once at windows loading. You probably want to bind it on the select `onchange` event.

E.g.:

```
function pickColor() {
    var colorPicker = document.getElementsByName("color").selectedIndex;
    var options = document.getElementsByName("color").options;

    document.getElementById("photo").src = carArray[options[colorPicker]];
}

<select name="color" onchange="pickColor()" multiple>
...
```

As @LightStyle suggests, you should avoid inline event assignments. I don't know your DOM, so for simplicity I'll add an id (it must be unique in the page) to your select. You can then do the following:

```
document.getElementById('color').onchange = function() {
    var colorPicker = document.getElementsByName("color").selectedIndex;
    var options = document.getElementsByName("color").options;

    document.getElementById("photo").src = carArray[options[colorPicker]];
}

<select name="color" id="color" multiple>
```

Comment: It's a bad practice to assign inline events in HTML, you should assign them via JS, collega ;)

Comment: I think there's a bunch of problems here. I just caught a syntax error and changed the event to onchange. However, the images are still not changing

Comment: Yes, there is the missing closing square bracket at the end of the function, you should correct the typo

Comment: There is another error now at for the document.getElementById("photo").src = carArray[options[colorPicker]]; line

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read propert 'undefined' of undefined

Comment: thanks @LightStyle for pointing it out, I updated the code, but I think there are some other worse design errors in this code..